# SELECT Query times out with when Dates are given as variables in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, between

I use SQL Server 2008 database.  I run a `view` on a linked server that connects to 6 different tables.  My query runs in less than a second if dates are hard coded.  However, it takes an infinite amount of time when the dates are given as @start and @stop.

```
-- SQL Server 2008
SELECT Date_, ID, Val1, Val2, 
       RowId=Row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY Date_, ID ORDER BY Val1 DESC)

FROM   ANOTHER_SERVER_DATABASE_VIEW AS V (NOLOCK) 

WHERE  V.ID IS NOT NULL AND V.Val2 <> 0 
       AND V.Date_ BETWEEN  '4/7/2014' AND '4/7/2014'
```

The View has some 120million rows.  However, the query returns just 20k rows.  It runs really fast when it is run as shown above. However when you include,

```
DECLARE @start AS DATETIME SET @start = '4/7/2014'
DECLARE @stop  AS DATETIME SET @stop  = '4/7/2014'

.......... AND V.Date_ BETWEEN @start AND @stop
```

the query returns the error:

```
OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "VIEW_SERVER" returned message "Query timeout expired".
Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 16
The OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "VIEW_SERVER" reported an error.     Execution terminated by the provider because a resource limit was reached.
Msg 7421, Level 16, State 2, Line 16
Cannot fetch the rowset from OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "VIEW_SERVER".
```

It is quite frustrating as V.Date_ = @start runs really fast as well.  Any idea why this abnormal behavior?  The 6 tables under the VIEW have NonClustered Index on the Date_ columns.

Comment: @Serpiton are you suggesting - .......... AND V.Date_ BETWEEN CAST(@start AS DATETIME) AND CAST(@stop AS DATETIME)?

Comment: @Serpiton While checking your suggestion something happened and it seems now SQL Server is running fine for BETWEEN start and stop. However, the new issue is it would timeout if I add INSERT INTO MyTable statement.  Its really weird.  My original question had to do with INSERT INTO problem with this statement but I found the issue to be related to BETWEEN date ranges.  Now date ranges miraculously are working fine but INSERT TO is failing.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect SQL Server is promoting `V.Date_` to a `datetime` because you've declared `@start` and `@stop` as `datetime` variables.  Thus it's likely doing a full table scan.  Try declaring them as `date` instead.

Comment: Date_ Columns in tables behind the view are all DATETIME.  I declared start & stop as DATE.  I now get error:
OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "VIEW_SERVER" returned message "Unspecified error".
OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "VIEW_SERVER" returned message "The scale is invalid.".
Msg 7322, Level 16, State 2, Line 17
A failure occurred while giving parameter information to OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "VIEW_SERVER".

Comment: Also the VIEW_SERVER uses SQL Server 2005.  I'm running the query on SQL Server 2008 though.  2 different servers, 2 different versions of SQL :(

Comment: It might be time to compare execution plans between the working and non-working queries.

Comment: estimated execution plans aren't helpful. You can't get the execution plan when the timeout errors happen.  Please see my comment above (to Serpiton)

Comment: Obviously bumping up the timeout is not the right solution, but if you do it temporarily you might be able to get an actual execution plan out of it.  Also, does setting `DBCC TRACEON (7300, 3604)` before the query give you any more informative errors?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using openquery() if you are not already doing so. This can allow the remote server's query optimizer to better analyze and optimize the query:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188427(v=sql.90).aspx

Also see:

'Best Performer: Distributed query (Four-part) or OPENQUERY when executing linked server queries in SQL Server'
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlsakthi/archive/2011/05/09/best-performer-distributed-query-four-part-or-openquery-when-executing-linked-server-queries-in-sql-server.aspx